# Recommended books for line geometry

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I would like to ask if there are any books for line geometry in english reffering to line complexes and congruences, Klein map etc (besides Pottman's)

Comment: You mean besides "Computational Line Geometry" of Pottman and Wallner ? This is an already very comprehensive and up-to-date book.

Comment: Yes, that's the book I'm reffering to. I want to approach line congruences from another perspective for my thesis and get a more complete view. I find that Pottmann's book is quite brief in some parts, so I'm looking for an alternative.